# How to use CSS to make this works on retina screen?

Tags: css, retina-display, retina

Code is like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/link-a"><img src="a.png"></a>
```

The image file a.png is 100x100 but on retina screen it's very ugly so I can generate a 2x PNG file. But how do I make it work in this HTML code?

Comment: you want resize image?

Comment: use media query to show respective image based on device-pixel-ratio

Comment: first I would suggest instead of using image use a `svg` format, but if you can't use 'svg' format than you can use `srcset` attribute.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I love svg, but I can't use it. Your idea `srcset` is awesome, thanks! Would you minding posting an answer with `srcset` solution?

Comment: just posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to go for `SVG` if you are using icons. However if you want to use image you can use `srcset` attribute.

```
<img src="image-src.png" srcset="image-1x.png 1x, image-2x.png 2x, image-3x.png 3x, image-4x.png 4x">
```

see [can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset)..

Comment: (@3x) use for iPhone 6 Plus :)

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be to use `svg` image which would fit in all resolutions.

But for your current code, you can use media query

HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/link-a"><img src="a.png" class="normalDisplay"><img src="abiggerresolution.png" class="retinaDisplay"></a>
```

In your CSS:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
   img.normalDisplay {
      display: none;
   }
    img. retinaDisplay {
      display: block;
   }
}
```

Pure JS solution:

```
var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1;

if(retina) {

 document.querySelector("img.specifyclassname").src="mention your higher resolution image link";

}
```

Another option would be: Use `retina.js` [link](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/).

The script will check your server to see if you have any image source with @2x at the end. It will replace that image with the higher resolution image.